# Drafts for the in-progress applications

Tags: mobile-application, data-tables, save, progress, industrial-design

I am working on a mobile application for license registration. After the user has selected his product and filled the required forms, he has to wait for the request to be confirmed. After request confirmation he can pay the invoice and have his own license. The problem that I am facing is in the 'Drafts' where I don't know how to showcase the best possible solution for huge table of data. I wonder if only putting search bar and ask for the application number and give permission to modify based on his application number or not. If not, what would be the idea for tables of drafts in mobile phone?

Comment: What does draft mean?

Comment: Drafts is for the applications which has not been submitted yet. Imagine that you have decided to apply for something but didn't complete the forms and the uncompleted application is considered as drafts now.

Comment: Wait a minute, why do you need to show a huge table of data in the Drafts? Usually users only request 1-2 licenses right? In that case why don't you just have a "Licenses" tab with their done, requested, and drafted licenses in it?

Answer (score 2):

Tables on mobile devices are not really recommended for good data visualization.
This has been discussed extensively in this thread here on stackexchange [Data tables in mobile/Tablet - material design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/80770/130031).

You may transform the table data into list or card view when it comes to mobile devices. You can consider going through this brief that gives insightful tips for designing tables for mobile devices. https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2020/07/designing-mobile-tables.php/

Key is to show user what is that bare minimum details that user can refer to, to identify the application to reopen on submit that is in Draft state.

Comment: Thank you Ashwin for your help.

Comment: Glad it could help. Please leave a upvote if it helped according to the community guidelines.